# cannot open shared library file while running program in arm machine

Tags: linux, arm, shared-libraries

I have build a program in linux(ubuntu 12.04) using arm-linux-gnueabi-g++.
The program compiles fine. When I transferred the program to an arm machine and tried to run I got this error:

error while loading shared libraries: libPVROCL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I copied the library to the /usr/local/lib folder of the arm machine but it did not work. I cannot change the conf file or environvent variables of the arm machine. The arm system is stripped down to the extent that it doesn't have ldconfig or ldd or much else. ldd run on another more capable system against the executable shows this line:
    not a dynamic executable
Can anyone give me a solution or show me a path? Any help will e appreciated.

I tried to build the code statically and I specified all the libraries with their full path. But I could not build as  it gives me another error:
attempted static link of dynamic object `/OpenCV/opencv/install/lib/libopencv_core.so'

Comment: Check on the host where you are compiling the shared library what are the dependencies. I am guessing you should be having `ldd` et al on the host. The error seems fairly straight forward, a dependency library `libPVROCL.so` (Power VR Open CL library? :)) is missing. Check on your arm target that you have this in `/lib`, or `/usr/lib/` or `/usr/local/lib` or where you put your libraries. Make sure that you have `libPVROCL.so` and not just something like `libPVROCL.so.1`

Comment: You do not need `ldd`; it is simply a shell script in some implementations.  Try `LD_DEBUG=all ./my_test` to run your program *my_test* or whatever it is.  This will show you where **ld.so** is trying to find **libPVROCL.so** and may give a hint as to why it is not found.  Place the output on *pastebin* or some place, if you can not diagnose the issue for yourself.